# Alter Procedure Package and Package Body PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I want to make an incremetal script for my oracle database.
I want to modify only one procedure signature and it's body and the rest should remain the same.

How can I accomplish this without recreating the hole package with create or replace?

---

**Example**

Old package

```
PROCEDURE LOAD_ITEMS(OUTCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

New package

```
PROCEDURE LOAD_ITEMS(P_ID IN CHAR, OUTCURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

---

**Edit:**
By incremental script, I mean upgrade script from previous version to this one.
And I want to modify only the current procedure, NOT ALL OF THEM.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to change a procedure in the package specification, then you need to
`CREATE OR REPLACE`
the whole package specification and body with the changed code.

---

While the [`ALTER PACKAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2005.htm) statement can be used to recompile the whole package, it

> [...] does not change the declaration or definition of an existing package. To redeclare or redefine a package, use the [`CREATE PACKAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6006.htm#i2091914) or the [`CREATE PACKAGE BODY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6007.htm#i2065383) statement with the `OR REPLACE` clause.

Comment: Please check the edit and the question. I want to modify a single procedure from the package, the rest remain untouched.

Comment: That doesn't matter.  A package is a single object in a database; you can't replace a single procedure/type/function within the body.  You have to define the entire body.  As you're changing the definition of a procedure that exists in the package spec, you have to redefine that too.

Comment: We might be able to help if we knew **why** you want to do that.

Comment: +1 Peter is correct: there is no way to do this.  The PACKAGE SPEC and PACKAGE BODY are the smallest units of change.

Comment: @Peter Lang add link to oracle documentation regarding your answer please.

Comment: see this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2005.htm